# How to debug this SQL query?

Tags: sql

I run this code and it does not work (I am expecting a result set but I do not get one):

```
select e.employee_id,e.first_name,e.last_name,e.salary,d.department_name,l.city from employees e 
join departments d on e.department_id = d.department_id
join locations l on l.location_id = d.location_id
where e.salary = select max(salary) from employees where hire_date between '2002-01-01' and '2003-12-31';
```

however if I run the queries

```
select max(salary) from employees where hire_date between '2002-01-01' and '2003-12-31';
```

and

```
select e.employee_id,e.first_name,e.last_name,e.salary,d.department_name,l.city from employees e 
join departments d on e.department_id = d.department_id
join locations l on l.location_id = d.location_id
where e.salary = 24000.00
```

they run fine. `max(salary)` from the second query is 24000.00.

This is the website where I am trying to practice (question no 34)
https://www.w3resource.com/sql-exercises/sql-subqueries-exercises.php

Comment: what do you mean by *doesn't work* ?

Comment: I dont get a result from the query. I am using a browser to write the code. this is the website https://www.w3resource.com/sql-exercises/sql-subqueries-exercises.php

Comment: On a sidenote: According to the SQL standard this: `'2002-01-01'` is a string literal, whereas this: `date '2002-01-01'` is a date literal. So precede your date strings with the word `date` in order to avoid string/date conversion and possible complications (though there are unlikely to be any).

Answer (score 1):

You are missing parenthesis for sub-query

```
SELECT e.employee_id,
       e.first_name,
       e.last_name,
       e.salary,
       d.department_name,
       l.city
FROM   employees e
       JOIN departments d
         ON e.department_id = d.department_id
       JOIN locations l
         ON l.location_id = d.location_id
WHERE  e.salary = (SELECT Max(salary)
                   FROM   employees
                   WHERE  hire_date BETWEEN '2002-01-01' AND '2003-12-31');
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use "IN" clause instead of "=" while filtering using a Subquery

```
SELECT e.employee_id,
       e.first_name,
       e.last_name,
       e.salary,
       d.department_name,
       l.city
FROM   employees e
       JOIN departments d
         ON e.department_id = d.department_id
       JOIN locations l
         ON l.location_id = d.location_id
WHERE  e.salary IN (SELECT Max(salary)
                    FROM   employees
                    WHERE  hire_date BETWEEN '2002-01-01' AND '2003-12-31');
```

Comment: `Max` without `Group by` is going to return a single record. So `=` should work.